# Call external JavaScript located inside iframe from java code using jsni

Tags: javascript, java, iframe, gwt, jsni

I am trying to call JavaScript method from Java using the following code

```
native void notifyJs() /*-{
    $wnd.foo();
}-*/;
```

The JavaScript method is located inside iframe and looks like

```
function foo() {
    alert("Do something");
}
```

But I am receiving this error

```
SEVERE: (TypeError) : $wnd.foo is not a functioncom.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : $wnd.foo is not a function
```

I have read that I should add myScript before `.nocache.js`, But I can not do that in my case. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Post an example code that I can execute and reproduce the issue, it's impossible to find the issue in these 3 line code sections. See - http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by replacing $wnd by $wnd.frames[0].
As the foo function is located inside this frame.

Comment: You should now accept your answer (instead if adding "solved" to the title)

Answer (score 0):

The error message says excactly what your problem is:
there is no function `foo` in the scope of `$wnd`.

`$wnd` refers to the parent of the iframe where your GWT code is running, so if you place your `foo` method inside the iframe it cant be found.
Try placing your `foo` method in your *.html file, where the `.nocache.js` is called.

Referring to your problem, that you add your javascript after the `.nocache.js`:
I had the same issue also and I fixed it with a timer, that waits until the Js is loaded.

```
private native boolean isLoaded()/*-{
    if (typeof $wnd.foo != 'undefined') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}-*/;

private void tryNotifyJs() {
    if (isLoaded()) {
        notifyJs();
    } else {
        Scheduler.get().scheduleFixedDelay(new RepeatingCommand() {

            @Override
            public boolean execute() {
                tryNotifyJs();
                return false;
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
```